# Python 3.6 is not default when I run a script

Tags: python, path, default

I have set the environment variables so that python 3.6 is the version that is run when I use the python command in the terminal, but when I run a python script from the terminal it uses python 2.7.

I have included a folder called MyScripts in the path so that i can run these scripts directly from the terminal without specifying the path.

Running just `python` shows Python 3.6.4

[image: > python]

But executing the script shows 2.7.14. This is the script **v27.py**

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
print(sys.executable)
```

And this is the output

[image: output from v27.py]

Comment: Type `path` in `cmd` and see which `python` path is set.

Comment: C:\Users\asleb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\

Comment: C:\Users\asleb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\MyScripts is also in the path, but when i run a script that is in this folder from the cmd. > myscript.py it will still use python 2.7

Comment: How are you running `v27.py`? Are you using `python v27.py`?

Comment: I am just typing `v27.py` without `python`. You can see this if you open this image output from v27.py in the post

Comment: I don't know much about Windows so can't help there, but I cleaned up the post a little. Hope you don't mind. Instead of images for program output it's usually best to post them as text, although in this case images do show the "proof" of what's happening, so it is still helpful. Good luck!

Comment: No problem, I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are running the Python Script (as a executable) without specifying `python` in command prompt, it will not use the python path set in *Environment Variables*. Instead, windows will run the Default Program associated for that extension. You can find the associated program under ***Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Default Programs\Set Associations***

Either you can go to ControlPanel to change the Default Program or your can run below command in `cmd` (need elevated permission to do this)

```
C:\> assoc .py=Python
C:\> ftype Python="C:\Users\asleb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe" "%1" %*
```

Also, if you want to run without extension (like `v27` instead of `v27.py`) then, you need to add `.py` to the PATHEXT environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Most OS systems use python2.7 as default python. Depending on your settings you have to call `python3` or call `/path/to/python3exacutable/python` to call the desired version.

If your project allows it, look into [anaconda](https://anaconda.org/) as a convenient python versioning solution.

Comment: How would you set up a folder so that you can run scripts from the terminal without specifying the path and have it run with python3?